# Order of Route in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I Use Symfony 3, And I Want to understand How symfony chouses the Route.

I have 3 routes, 2 in routing.yml and 1 in annotation.
this is my code:

app/config/routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

hello:
    path: "hello/{firstName}"
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Default:rotta,firstName: "route1"}

hello_name:
    path: "hello/{firstName}"
    defaults:  {_controller: AppBundle:Default:rotta, firstName: "route2"}
```

src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
/**
 * @Route("hello/{firstName}", name="hello", defaults={"firstName" = "Annotation"})
 */
public function rottaAction($firstName,Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->get('firstName'));
    exit;
}
```

My result is

```
string 'route1' (length=6)
```

with this routing.yml

```
hello:
    path: "hello/{firstName}"
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Default:rotta,firstName: "route1"}

hello_name:
    path: "hello/{firstName}"
    defaults:  {_controller: AppBundle:Default:rotta, firstName: "route2"}

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

My result is

```
string 'route2' (length=6)
```

and with this combination:

```
hello:
    path: "hello/{firstName}"
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Default:rotta,firstName: "route1"}

hello_name:
    path: "hello/{firstName}"
    defaults:  {_controller: AppBundle:Default:rotta, firstName: "route2"}

#app:
#    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
#    type:     annotation
```

my result is:

```
string 'route1' (length=6)
```

Comment: Rename route in annotation to `hello_annotation`. Route names are keys for routes in collection, so route `hello` is allways rewritten.

Comment: Yes, now I Understand. Thanks Max

Comment: Bonus tip: You can use `bin/console debug:router` to get all routes.

Comment: Is your question about the order of routes in YAML vs. routes in annotations?

Comment: @A.L yes the order and the mix of yaml and annotation

Comment: The order is easier to understand if you don't mix yaml with annotations.  Pick one or the other. Mixing them often leads to an early demise.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, I use annotation, but my purpose is to understand how symfony works